# Call number on page load / document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I need to create a blank webpage with the url like: https://www.example.com/callme and we will share the link with our customers.
When someone clicks the link, a blank page will load, and as soon as the document is ready or dom content loaded, it has to automatically dial a specific number on mobile devices.
Basically you can do this with a link tag with href "tel:xxxxx", but i need it to be automatically clicked when the page load, not to click/tap it manually.
Here is what i tried so far but with no success:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 $('#call').trigger('click');
}, false);
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#call').click();
});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#call').trigger('click');
});
```

and here is the simple html:

```
<a href="tel:142;" id="call">Call me</a>
```

Any advice is much appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Simply include this one-liner to change your client's url to your `tel`-link

```
window.location.href="tel:123456789";
```

If they are on a device that has a handler for `tel`-links (a mobile-phone for example) their phone app will open and give them the opportunity to call you

Comment: thank you for your input.
but why it doesn't work if the script executes the click event, which will change the href to "tel:xxxxxx" ?

Comment: self-executing function is not needed here.

Comment: @GillesC , so in my case, if we don't need a self executing fn, the document ready should be used? or something like that? which is kind of half-self-executing. what is your point anyway? 
thank you

Comment: @GillesC right, I tend to make problems harder than they are from time to time

Comment: @Luca it is not working on my mobile device, but it is working on my desktop lol, it opens skype for business to handle the `tel`.